# How to make a layout from going up on soft keyboard display?

Tags: java, android, layout

Every time i try to type in the edittext everything goes up and the header disappears. How do i make a linearlayaout linear1 stay put when i try to type in the edittext. i also tried adding "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">" to the manifest and it is still not working.

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#5D4037"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#f0f0f0" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mess"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollbarSize="40dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is me java class

```
import com.obi.thinker.logins.R;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Chatting extends ListActivity {
EditText mess;


    ImageButton send;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.yon);

mess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mess);
mess.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
            }
        }
    });

    }



}
```

I don't want the soft keyboard to push the header . it should push only the list view up.

Comment: Yes but the nothing goes up but i just want the list view to go up. like in whatapps chat

Comment: Your activity is full screen and there is no title bar so all the content will definitely go up.

Comment: so it i put a title bar how do i make is stay put .

Comment: try to add `android:isScrollContainer="false"` in your parent Relative layout and put your `linearlayaout linear1` in a `ScrollView` with `android:isScrollContainer="true"`.

Comment: the linear layout disappears when i put it in a scrollview...... is there any other way to do this

Comment: what do you mean by disappear? When the softkeyboard opens or in editor?